# Convert .htaccess to web.config 1

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-config

how to convert .htaccess to web.config?

```
Options All -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectoryIndex bot.php
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|php|xml|ini)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "bot\.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks :)